# Navigation change doesn't get triggered when calling it inside callback block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have the task of making some small adjustments in a bigger Objective-C app.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on an item in a list, a calculation will be executed and depending on the outcome, the navigation should pop back to root and display an error. Because I do not have access to the NavigationController in the class where the calculation is done, I tried to pass a "callback block".

```
[self.baseBehaviour processInfo:info completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
  NSLog(finished ? @"YES" : @"NO");
  // pop back to root controller
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }];
```

I pass that block along until the calculation is done and call the callback. It seems to work fine because I can see YES or NO in the logs, but the navigation is not triggered for some reason. It also does not seem to be a scoping issue because self seems to be the same reference (and I even tried to make a new variable for the navigationController, but that didn't help either).

If I take out `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and move it out of the callback (so it gets executed immediately), it works perfectly. But obviously that doesn't help me because at that time I did not determine if I need to go back or not.

Am I missing something obvous or is there a way to see (in the debugger) why the animation doesn't get triggered?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I was trying this while testing, but it also didn't seem to work:

```
    [self.baseBehaviour processInfo:self.info completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(finished ? @"YES" : @"NO");
            // pop back to root controller
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    }];
```

EDIT2:

It looks like it could be a scoping problem after all. I noticed that when I did `` then it was nil in the debugger.

```
NSArray *viewCtrls = [self.navigationController viewControllers]; // 3 elements

[self.baseBehaviour processInfo:self.info completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(finished ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        // pop back to root controller
        NSArray *viewCtrls = [self.navigationController viewControllers]; // nil
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    });
}];
```

How can I "pass" something into the callback block, like the navigationController?

Comment: completion block will execute in secondary thread. So Create a main thread there(`NSOperationQueue` or `NSThread`), and pop to root controller.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another code snippet that sadly also doesn't work. Is it possible that the animation doesn't get triggered because another animation (push) is already running?

Comment: In the last argument, pass `NO` instead of YES. I also edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191471/988169).

Answer (score 1):

Do it in main thread, for instance :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];});
```

This may help u

Answer (score 1):

completion block will execute in secondary thread. Pushing or poping a view controller must be in main thread. So Create a main thread there and pop to root controller

```
    [self.baseBehaviour processInfo:info completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
      NSLog(finished ? @"YES" : @"NO");
      // pop back to root controller
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];});


     }];
```

Your issue in comment:- Is it possible that the animation doesn't get triggered because another animation (push) is already running?
Answer:- If you are facing issue with animation glitches, then pass `NO` while popping a view controller as follows:-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I updated my answer, sadly it didn't work.

Comment: That still doesn't work. The problem is that it doesn't get triggered at all, so it does not go back at all. Will a navigation change be blocked if another navigation is already running?

Comment: What are the other navigations? Other navigation controllers are also pushing or popping view controllers?

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it is a scoping issue after all.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried that and it sadly didn't work.

Comment: Please check the `rootViewController`, is it the desired one?

Comment: I think so, otherwise it also wouldn't work when I place it outside of the callback, right?